# Pass a closure (without comma or parens) as a last parameter of a function in Groovy

Tags: groovy

How can I call the `label` function and set a closure to it as the last parameter in this way? This code works only if I call `label` with parentheses but I don't need them. Is it possible to set the closure into function without them?

```
label = { name, callback ->
    callback()
}

label "lbl" {    // not works
    println "call $it"
}

label ("lbl") {  // works
    println "call $it"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to use parentheses then you have to split closure arguments with `,` to tell the compiler that you want to execute `label` with following two parameters:

```
label "lbl", {    
    println "call $it"
}
```

This notation is equivalent of:

```
label("lbl", {    
    println "call $it"
})
```

Groovy has this syntactic sugar that allows you passing closure outside parenthesis when closure is the last parameter of a function prototype, that's why following notation works:

```
label ("lbl") {
    println "call $it"
}
```

But it is still an equivalent of the ones mentioned earlier.

> ### How to make `label "lbl" { }` a valid statement?
>
> If you really want to compile code like:
>
> ```
> label "lbl" {    
>     println "call $it"
> }
> ```
>
> you need to be aware of one thing - such notation is an equivalent of:
>
> ```
> label("lbl" {    
>     println "call $it"
> })
> ```
>
> It means that there is a function `label` that accepts single parameter - a value returned from `lbl` function that accepts a single parameter - closure. The implementation of these functions might look like this:
>
> ```
> def label = { value ->
>   // do something with value
>   println "The value accepted by label function is '${value}'"
> }
>
> def lbl = { callback ->
>   callback?.call()
> }
>
> label "lbl" {
>   println "call $it"
> }
> ```
>
> It compiles and it prints following output to console:
>
> ```
> call null
> The value accepted by label function is 'null'
> ```
>
> Of course as you can see you have to implement method `lbl` and in most cases this is very limiting - you can't call `label` function with any parameter different than `lbl`. You could implement Groovy's `methodMissing(name, args)` function that gets called whenever non-existing method gets invoked. Consider following example:
>
> ```
> def methodMissing(String name, args) {
>
>   if (args.length == 1 && args[0] instanceof Closure) {
>     println "Running missing method '${name}'"
>     return args[0].call()
>   }
>
>   throw new MissingMethodException(name, this.class, args)
> }
>
> def label = { value ->
>   // do something with value
>   println "The value accepted by label function is '${value}'"
> }
>
> def lbl = { callback ->
>   callback?.call()
> }
>
> label "lbl" {
>   println "call $it"
> }
>
> label "test" {
>   println "nothing"
> }
> ```
>
> In this case when `label "test" { println "nothing" }` gets invoked, Groovy uses `missingMethod` because method `test` does not exist in the runtime context.
>
> ```
> call null
> The value accepted by label function is 'null'
> Running missing method 'test'
> nothing
> The value accepted by label function is 'null'
> ```
>
> However **it doesn't mean, that you can think about this as an equivalent of getting rid of coma separator or parenthesis from your code**. This is an example of a simple DSL written with Groovy that uses `methodMissing` mechanism to satisfy non-existing methods invocation. This last example is actually the same as:
>
> ```
> label("test" {
>   println "nothing"
> })
> ```
>
> A function that expects a single argument and in this case we provide it as a result of `test` method invocation with a single parameter `{ println "nothing" }`.
>
> I would strongly suggest accepting the fact that Groovy requires you to separate function arguments with a coma and don't use such DSL to remove coma or parenthesis from the code. Groovy DSL is very powerful and you have to know what you are doing when you decide using this tool in your code. For instance, think about what happens if you call:
>
> ```
> label "test" { println "something" }
> ```
>
> and for some reason a method defined as a following closure:
>
> ```
> def test = { int num -> num + 2 }
> ```
>
> exists in your class. You will start getting exceptions, because `methodMissing` is not called anymore in this case. Method `test` exists, but it does not have a signature that accepts a single closure.

Comment: Yeah, I know about comma separation, but it's ugly in my case too. I would like to do without it or parentheses. Is this possible?

Comment: @lancaster Why ugly? Simple answer to your question - removing coma as a function parameters separator is not possible. You can write a DSL with Groovy that will compile code like `label "lbl" { println "something" }`, however it wont be a function `label` that expects two parameters, but function `label` that accepts a result of `"lbl" { println "something" }`. I have explained this in the updated answer.

Comment: Oh thank you. I override `methodMissing` at String's metaclass and now all works and looks pretty fine.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of directly invoking the closure within the `methodMissing` method, you can defer to Groovy's dynamic dispatch by returning a list from `methodMissing`:`return [name, args[0]]`